# How to assembly multiple executable JARs from a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module, maven-module

I have a multi-module project like this

```
foobar
 |
 +-- pom.xml
 |
 +-- common-lib/
 |       |
 |       +-- pom.xml
 |       +-- src/
 |
 +-- foo-app/
 |       |
 |       +-- pom.xml
 |       +-- src/
 |
 +-- bar-app/
 |       |
 |       +-- pom.xml
 |       +-- src/
 |
-+-
```

Both `foo-app` and `bar-app` depend on code in `common-lib` and also on dependencies in their own POMs.

Using `mvn package` I can build three light JARs.

What I want is two executable JARs, each with dependencies included, for:

- foo-app
- bar-app

How do I do this with maven?

---

In case anyone suggests it, due to clashes between the dependencies for `foo-app` and `bar-app` I cannot merge them into one single foobar-app.

Comment: I'm confused why this is an issue.  Are there "clashes between dependencies" within common-lib?

Comment: foo-app requires fdep. bar-app requires bdep. You cannot build a project that uses both fdep and bdep in the same JVM instance, they've both bundled different versions of netty into their JARs leading to AbstractMethodError exceptions at runtime. Hence I split foobar-app into foo-app and bar-app. Now I want a maven configuration for this three-module project that will generate two executable jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add maven assembly plugin to the pom.xml's which you want to create a executable jar with dependencies. Execute `mvn package` on aggregator pom.xml. This command will execute `mvn package` command on all the sub modules. The ones that have maven assembly plugin will generate executable jars with dependencies.

In your case add this to foo-app and bar-app projects pom.xml. And configure your `<mainClass>your.package.mainclass</mainClass>` according to each projects main class.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>your.package.mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What I get is `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1:assembly (default-cli) on project foobar: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]` where`foobar` refers to the parent POM

Comment: @Feenaboccles did you add the above configuration to foobar project. also which command did you execute. your error mentions 2.4.1 version of assembly.

Comment: It’s not in the `foobar` project, just `foo-app` and `bar-app`. I executed `mvn  assembly:assembly`

Comment: @Feenaboccles I suggest you to read the answer. you should execute mvn package command.